# How to limit the number of @ViewScoped beans

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, mojarra

I'm using GF4. In my app I have a main menu which is always visible to the user. One of the menu items refers to a `@ViewScoped` backing bean, which is being created and its `@PostConstruct` method called every time the user clicks on this menu item, which is the expected behavior.

**The problem** arises when the user clicks on some other menu item, because the @ViewSoped bean continues to exist, i.e. its `@PreDestroy` method is not being called.

Looking for an answer I came across this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105439/com-sun-faces-numberofviewsinsession-vs-com-sun-faces-numberoflogicalviews) which proposes setting those two parameters:
`com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession` and`com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews`.
Since I want only one @ViewScoped bean at a time I set them both in *web.xml* to `1`. But this has no effect! Hence my questions:

1. Is *web.xml* the right place?
2. Is there a way to affect the container managed beans, i.e. manually destroy them?

   Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this answer does help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15391453/1803294

Comment: Thank you, that answer was not the direct solution, but in it there is a link to another Q&A, which in turn provides a working solution :) I'm going to provide below detailed information as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here [JSF 2.2 Memory Consumption: Why does Mojarra keep the ViewScoped Beans of the last 25 Views in Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959982/jsf-2-2-memory-consumption-why-does-mojarra-keep-the-viewscoped-beans-of-the-la). The user there provides the solution in his question. So one have to implement a custom `HttpSessionListener` as described there.

To make the solution complete I'm adding the configuration part. Supposed your implementation looks like this:

```
 public class CustomViewMapConfig implements HttpSessionListener
 {
     @Override
     public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)
     {
         event.getSession().setAttribute(ViewScopeManager.ACTIVE_VIEW_MAPS_SIZE, 1);
     }
 }
```

then the corresponding *web.xml* looks like this:

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.CustomViewMapConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>
    ...
</web-app>
```